# Making equal left and right hand side of the some equality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I think that there is a similar posts in here. But I don't find right keyword.

My question:
After some calculations, I get equality. For a simple example:

$$list=\{a,b,c\}==\{1,2,3\}$$

Can we extract $a=1,b=2,c=3$.

I want to make some calculations such as $a+b+c=?,  D[a*c,x]=? $ e.t.c

What are the best options?

```
`list = {a, b, c} == {1, 2, 3};
Thread[{a, b, c} == {1, 2, 3}, Equal];
a + b + c
```

`D[a*c,x]`

Comment: `Total[list[[2]]]`?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But it is just simple example for the convenience.  I want to do other calculations besides addition

Comment: `Thread[Set @@ list]` may be what you want.

Comment: @Somos thank you. It's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
list = {a, b, c} == {1, 2, 3};
```

I would use

```
a + b + c /. Thread[Rule @@ list]
(* 6 *)
```